# How to factor$ x^2+2xy+y^2 $

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I know the formula $x^2 + 2xy + y^2 = (x + y)^2$ by heart and in order to understand it better I am trying to solve the formula myself; however, I don't understand how step 4 is derived from step 3.

$$x^2+2xy+y^2\qquad1$$

$$x^2+xy+xy+y^2\qquad2$$

$$x(x+y) + y(x+y) \qquad3$$

$$(x+y)(x+y) \qquad 4$$

How does one get from step 3 to step 4? I don't know how to do that process.

Comment: This is simply factoring $(x + y)$ from each term. If it isn't clear how to do try, first try reversing the step by distributing the first sum in (4).

Comment: @Brevan Ellefsen thanks for editing, i don't know how to put square on x.

Comment: I know step 4 can lead to step 3 in reverse but how to get step 4 from 3.  i don't understand the theory behind it.

Comment: Sure thing. I figured you would get more answers if the question is worded better... for many people that is a great turnoff.

Comment: I am looking up other solutions online to see if another solution exists now, but as I noted prior, if you prove that $a=b$ than the statement $b=a$ is proven mathematically... this is how we prove many things in math, and you can't always go the other way.

Comment: Riaz, I found another solution online.... it basically over complicated things to the point where the problem is very hard to understand, but it does satisfy your criteria.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen I agree with you but i couldn't convince my school teacher. He asked us for explanation of step 3 to step 4. I searched the internet all day but no luck that's why i put the question here, if someone can explain the theory behind it. Finger cross

Comment: The simplest solution is this: $$x(x+y)+y(x+y) = xz+yz = z(x+y) = (x+y)(x+y)$$ where z = x+y, but this is basically just distributing... other than the other link I gave I don't know what else you're going to find. When you talk to the instructor I would just use this proof. It is basically the one you accepted but simplified as much as possible.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Thanks very much. Yes this is what i was missing, putting different character "z" made it much easier for me to understand.  Once again thanks for all your effort.

Comment: @David K. Thanks for further editing and improving it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First consider this:

$3$ apples and $4$ apples make $7$ apples.

You may represent this as:

$3A+4A=7A$

But let's let  $A=x+y$

$3(x+y)+4(x+y)=7(x+y)$

Or equivalently:

$(3+4)(x+y)$

Now consider:

$x(x+y)+y(x+y)$

Let's let $A=x+y$ like we did in the above.

Now we have:

$xA+yA$

Factor the $A$ out

$=A(x+y)$

plug $A$ back in

$=(x+y)(x+y)$

Comment: S.Attaalla Fantastic, thanks for the clear example, this step (3+4)(x+y) cleared all my confusion. I got it now thanks very much.

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully some colouring will make things easier to grasp:
$$\color{red}{x}(x+y)+\color{blue}{y}(x+y)=(\color{red}{x}+\color{blue}{y})(x+y)=(x+y)^2.$$

Comment: cool indeed colouring made it much easier, i will use this method to teach my class fellows. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Simply, Step 4 is known as factoring by grouping. It is essentially an inverse of distribution, and can be proven by distributing $(a+b)(a+b)$ to get $a(a+b) + b(a+b)$.

(Note: a more complete solution can be found at the following link:
http://www.onemathematicalcat.org/algebra_book/online_problems/facByGrpPf.htm
However, this solution is very complicated and I could barely follow it without paying deep attention. This is the only way I know of to prove factoring by grouping without just distributing.)

Comment: I know that it can be proved by distributing (a+b)(a+b) to get a(a+b)+b(a+b). But my question is a(a+b)+b(a+b) to get (a+b)(a+b) . I looking some explanation for that

Comment: Riaz, if $a=b$ then $b=a$.... once you prove one the other is proven also.

Comment: Thanks very much for all your help, i was blind i couldn't see it.  I got it now thanks to Ahmad S. Attalla. I was missing the very basic step and Ahmad's example made it very clear to me.

Answer (score 1):

$$x\color{blue}{(x+y)} + y \color{blue}{(x+y)} \qquad3$$

Let $\color{blue}{b=(x+y)}$
So, now you have. 
$$x\color{blue}{(b)} + y\color{blue}{(b)}  = x\color{blue}{b} +y\color{blue}{b} =\color{blue}{b}x+\color{blue}{b}y $$

Now factor out the $\color{blue}{b}# :

$$\color{blue}{b} (x+y)$$

Remember, $\color{blue}{b=x+y}$, so substitute:

$$\color{blue}{(x+y)}(x +y)=(x+y)^2$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: go the other way! start with $(x + y)^2$, multiply out to get $x^2 + y^2 + xy + yx$ and then collect like terms to get the normal form $x^2 + 2xy + y^2$. "Multiplying out and collecting like terms" is a decision procedure for this kind of problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's simply a common binomial factor. Common factors don't have to be just a variable or a number; they can be any written expression. Suggest that you find a section in a textbook labelled "factor by grouping" and practice several problems there.

Obviously $xb + yb = b(x + y)$. If you see that, your problem is identical with the replacement $b = (x + y)$.

As a side issue, derivations like this are generally easier to accomplish going from complicated-to-simplified form. Start with $(x + y)^2$ and simplify it; you'll probably find it more straightforward (just expand and FOIL).